# Catch boolean modifier error

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to catch boolean modifier errors?
There is a yellow flag in modifier and "CSG Failed..." error in console, but if i put my code to create boolean modifier in a try-catch statement, no error is thrown...
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you upload a blendfile that demonstrates the error you're having with the boolean modifier? Use: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I know how to resolve the error. I have just to move a little bit my operand but i would know when i have to fix it. That's why i want to catch errors in my code.

Comment: If you have errors in code, post the code.  Are you saying the modifier worked in try except block or is just being caught?

Comment: There is no error in code, boolean modifier is well created but the "CSG Failed exception" is not caugth in the try block.
I think that this exception is a C++ exception but not a python exception... Can i catch a C++ exception in Python?